# How to get size of file chosen by user (autohotkey)?

Tags: browser, key, autohotkey, filesize

Basically, I am quite new to autohotkey and was wondering if it was possible to make a script so that when a button is pressed, a file browser pops-up, you then select as many files as you want, but if the size of the file exceeds 1000MB then you cannot select anymore files, after this the files you have are copied to a USB stick in the computer, also, how would i go about making sure the file browser cannot open any files (i.e you cant just right click and click open when browsing for files, you can only select files?
Thankyou,

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Checking the size and copying the files selected will not be an issue.  However, disabling opening of files would be the tricky part.  Why do you need this restricted?

Answer (score 0):

Ha, I was just looking at that function today!

Take a look at `FileGetSize`

Here is what is in the docs:

> Files of any size are supported, even those over 4 gigabytes, and even
>   if Units is bytes.
>
> If the target file is a directory, the size will be reported as
>   whatever the OS believes it to be (probably zero in all cases).
>
> To calculate the size of folder, including all its files, follow this
>   example:

```
SetBatchLines, -1  ; Make the operation run at maximum speed. 
FolderSize = 0 FileSelectFolder, WhichFolder  ; Ask the user to pick a folder. 
Loop, %WhichFolder%\*.*, , 1
    FolderSize += %A_LoopFileSize% 
MsgBox Size of %WhichFolder% is %FolderSize% bytes.
```

As far as fixing it so the files cannot be opened, well, when you use the `FileOpen` dialogue (check that out in the docs; it's powerful easy), you can choose exactly what to do with that file.

Basically, you don't "disable" the opening of files, you just do something else instead!

For example, if you run this as a script, it will show the file-browser dialogue, but instead of opening the file in any program, it will run the `FileGetSize` function on it and then display a messagebox with the file size:

```
gosub, fileopen

FileOpen:
    FileSelectFile, thisfile, 3,startdirectory, Select Files, Any File (*.*; *.gabc)

    if(thisfile){
        filegetsize, thisfilesize, %thisfile%
        msgbox, %thisfilesize%
        return
    }else{
        return
    }
return
```

To get it to work on all the selected files, you'll have to use a loop statement.  What I would do is to loop through all the files selected and get their filesize into a variable, and then at the end of the loop, display the messagebox.